# How to get one unique record from the same list of records from table? No Unique constraint in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one query in SQL Server output,

Suppose i have one table (Ex.StudentMaster) having some fields-No unique constraints. 
For Ex. RollNumber and Name
The table has same same data. For ex:

```
RollNo      Name
    1       Yoko
    1       Yoko
    1       Yoko
```

I want to get only third record. How can i identify this unique record?

Comment: What version of SQL Server?  It matters if 2005+, or not.  And how you determine what is the latest row when there's nothing available to distinguish between duplicates.

Comment: Does it matter's if it is first, second or third row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any row is a third row :-)

```
create table test
(
n int,
name varchar(30)
);

insert into test values(1,'yoko'),(1,'yoko'),(1,'yoko');

select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by name) as ordinal, * from test;
```

Deleting the "third" row :-)

```
with a as
(
select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by name) as ordinal, * from test
)
delete from a where a.ordinal = 3
```

Deleting the last row:

```
with a as
(
select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by name) as ordinal, * from test
)
delete from a where a.ordinal = (select MAX(ordinal) from a)
```

Comment: That's how I'd do it, but it is SQL Server 2005+ functionality.

Comment: I put the answer anyway, better be FGITW than wait eon for his answer what version he is using, when for all we know, he might be using the latest version ;-)

Comment: In case of SQL server 2000(!) http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3572301/RowNumber-function-in-SQL-Server-2005.htm

Comment: Thanks, i got the Solution with "select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by name) as ordinal, * from test"

Answer (score 1):

You can use DISTINCT which return's distinct combination's of columns.

```
SELECT DISTINCT RollNo, Name
FROM mytable
```

Comment: Yes,this is true. But the thing is i want a particular record only. Using DISTINCT will give me single record but i will not be knowing which record it is, First,second or third.