# select with start, stop and rowcount, need total

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this oracle sql which gives me a subset of records for paging. I also need the total of records, can I combine the two queries ? The real query is much more complicated (union with where etc), I simplified it to not distract from my question.

```
select count(*) from table;
select outerfields.* from 
 (select row_number() over (order by id asc) r, innerfields.* from 
   ( (select * from table) innerfields)) outerfields where r between 1 and 10;
```

obviously something like the following doesn't work

```
select max(r), outerfields.* from 
  (select row_number() over (order by id asc) r, innerfields.* 
    from ( (select * from m30brief) innerfields)) outerfields where r between 1 and 10;
```

Comment: You can do this with "PARTITION BY".
Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477085/oracle-partition-by-and-row-number-keyword

Comment: i read this but when i add the partition by to the over i get all the records, not a subset, could you answer with the modified query please ?

Comment: Is there something wrong with my answer? `Partition by` will not help here.

Comment: @Nikola, no there isn't, it works and will accept it, only I hoped to learn a better technique from this suggestion to get the same result, but since you say i won't i believe you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `count(*) over()` to `outerfields` derived table:

```
select outerfields.* 
  from 
  (
    select row_number() over (order by id asc) r, 
           count(*) over () totalRows,
           innerfields.* 
      from 
      (
        select * 
          from table
      ) innerfields
  ) outerfields
 where r between 1 and 10;
```