# SQL max() over(partition) returning multiple results

Tags: sql, max, partition-by

I have a simple query that I'm using to try and understand the SQL max() over() functionality as follows:

```
select *, max(mt.version) over (partition by mt.version)
from myTable mt
where mt.id = 'some uuid';
```

**Edit:** *This concept is new to me so I'm not sure what it is supposed to do.  I don't have a specific data set, I'm just simply trying to understand what the code is doing by coming up with my own example.*

The thing I don't understand is that I am getting multiple rows with my data set.  I thought the max() over(partition by x) functionality was supposed to return a single result based off of the max function.  Will someone please explain why I would get more than 1 result.  I tried this on a different table and it works fine but on another table it doesn't work.

Comment: Well, you're only taking one maximum for each distinct value of `mt.version`... In fact, since you're taking the max of `mt.version` and partitioning it by `mt.version`, I don't think you'll get any new data. What are you **actually** trying to do?

Comment: Why did you use `over` if you don't know what it does? It's optional, you know? It looks like you just want the `max` without `over (partition by)`

Comment: I'm playing around with it as suggested in the question as suggested by the text, "understand ... functionality".  I saw something similar online and was trying to figure out what it did.  Hence using it when I don't know what it does...  That's how you learn isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was taking the max of mt.version and partitioning it by mt.version so I wasn't getting any new data.  A correct version of what I previously wrote could be:

```
select *, max(mt.version) over (partition by mt.partitiongroup)
from mytable mt
where mt.id = 'some uuid';
```

I wasn't realizing while trying out this new concept that the partition group had to be different than the max aggregation.

Comment: +1 for correct understanding. This is similar to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477085/oracle-partition-by-and-row-number-keyword/

Comment: Thank you @Michael for the link. That helps with my understanding as well.