# Performing SQL select distinct except BLOB field

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I need to select some DISTINCT fields on a table, but I need to exclude blobs from the distinct, since distinct does not consider BLOB fields.

I tried looking for something here, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26721525/oracle-how-can-i-perform-a-select-distinct-on-all-fields-except-a-blob) is what I found and it doesn't work for me,

```
Invalid token.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
Token unknown - line 3, column 76.
(.
----------------------------------
SQLCODE: -104
SQLSTATE: 42000
GDSCODE: 335544569
```

This is the query I used (I modified names since it's from work)

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3, Blob1, Blob2
FROM (     
  SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3, Blob1, Blob2, row_number() over (partition by Field1, Field2, Field3 order by Field1) RW
  FROM Table
) WHERE RW = 1;
```

Is there any other way to do it other than the one suggested in that article?

Comment: You probably could use the query suggested by that question if you were using Firebird 3 or higher, as that is the version that introduced window functions like `row_number()`.

Comment: What do you want to happen if there are multiple rows with Field1, Field2, Field3 and different blob values? Do you want any blob (doesn't matter which), or do you want all distinct blobs?

Comment: For Firebird 2 try `RDB$DB_KEY` hidden column instead of `row_number()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you found in the other question is a syntax error in Firebird 2.5, but would likely work in Firebird 3.0 (though I didn't verify that), as that is the version that introduced window functions like `row_number()`.

However, if you just want a blob (doesn't matter which one) for the combination of fields, then you can do:

```sql
select a.field1, a.field2, a.field3,
  (select first 1 blob1 from table1 where field1 = a.field1 and field2 = a.field2 and field3 = a.field3) as blob1,
  (select first 1 blob2 from table1 where field1 = a.field1 and field2 = a.field2 and field3 = a.field3) as blob2
from (
  select distinct field1, field2, field3
  from table1
) a
```

or

```sql
select field1, field2, field3, min(blob1) as blob1, min(blob2) as blob2
from table1
group by field1, field2, field3
```

This query might result in blob1 and blob2 from different rows.

If you want all the different blobs, then you could do something like the following (this isn't 100% fool-proof, as `hash` can produce collisions, and it will likely be extremely slow):

```sql
select b.field1, b.field2, b.field3, b.blob1, b.blob2
from (
  select distinct field1, field2, field3, hash(blob1) as hash1, hash(blob2) as hash2
  from table1
) a
inner join table1 b
  on b.field1 = a.field1 and b.field2 = a.field2 and b.field3 = a.field3
    and hash(b.blob1) = a.hash1 and hash(b.blob2) = a.hash2
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i tried a different approach using a query to load a cds with the distinct values then another query to look for the first row of each distinct row to get the blobs. I accepted your answer since it's complete and trying it I found out it is what i was looking for

Comment: @DenisNdoja If you found a different approach, consider posting your own answer with that approach. Who knows, it could be helpful to someone else in the future!

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. What I did, since i had to use it in delphi software i just got all the records i needed and filtered them by code. So that's why i didn't post it as an answer right away, it's not in the scope of the question, it's too specific and i didn't even use sql to solve it.