# Oracle get first record from result set

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have a query like, below which gives the following results. For one given pcid there may be one or more images. I only want to grab the first record if the pcid has more than 1 images returned. I know distinct will not work in this case. Any ideas will be appreciated. thanks

```
select p.pcid,p.pc_name,p.pc_image_name
from pc p LEFT JOIN pc_goods pcm on p.pcid = pcm.pcid AND pcm.media_type = 'I' 
AND pcm.act_ind = 'Y' AND pcm.fea_ind = 'Y' INNER JOIN pc_cat pcat 
ON p.category_id = pcat.cat_id 
and p.fea_ind = 'Y' AND p.act_ind = 'Y'
order by pcid

Current results     
    pcid    pc_name   pc_image_name
    --------------------------------
    1120    testone   one.jpg
    1120    testwo    two.jpg
    1121    testthree three.png
    1125    testfour  four.png
    1128    test5     five.jpg
    1128    test6     six.jpg
```

Desired results,

```
pcid    pc_name   pc_image_name
--------------------------------
1120    testone   one.jpg
1121    testthree three.png
1125    testfour  four.png
1128    test5     five.jpg
```

Comment: How do you denote "First" is there a date time or do you just need any record?  If so you could always use min on image name in a subquery then join back..  Use an inline view of the PC_goods table to return a single record for each PCID using min/max then join it into the result set .  Or you could generate a row number field and return where it's only 1 for each PCiD. [Example:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477085/oracle-partition-by-and-row-number-keyword)

Comment: Yes it is any img record

Comment: I don't see why your query needs to do a left join on `pc_goods`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `row_number` window function for this:

```
row_number() over (partition by p.pcid order by null) as rn
```

...where you partition by `pcid`. Since you don't seem to care which image is picked, you can just order by any constant value (I used a `null` in this case).

```
select pcid,pc_name,pc_image_name
  from (
     select p.pcid,p.pc_name,p.pc_image_name,
            row_number() over (partition by p.pcid order by null) as rn
    from pc p LEFT JOIN pc_goods pcm on p.pcid = pcm.pcid AND pcm.media_type = 'I' 
    AND pcm.act_ind = 'Y' AND pcm.fea_ind = 'Y' INNER JOIN pc_cat pcat 
    ON p.category_id = pcat.cat_id 
    and p.fea_ind = 'Y' AND p.act_ind = 'Y')
 where rn = 1
 order by pcid
```

Comment: Thanks! this works perfectly, Is there a simple example to explain the partiionby and row_number() functions? I am not very familiar with these and I know these come very handy in oracle. I did try to look up online but most of them are too complicated.

Comment: [General analytic function information](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174) and [row_number specific info](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions156.htm#SQLRF06100)

Answer (score 1):

Without testing or addressing why a left join is needed...
something like this would probably work provided an imageName is unique.

```
SELECT p.pcid,p.pc_name,p.pc_image_name
FROM pc p 
LEFT JOIN pc_goods pcm 
  on p.pcid = pcm.pcid AND pcm.media_type = 'I' 
 AND pcm.act_ind = 'Y' AND pcm.fea_ind = 'Y' 
INNER JOIN (SELECT max(pc_image_name) maxImage, pcID from PC_GOODS group by PCID) PCM2
 on PCM2.maxImage=PCM.Pc_image_name 
and PCM2.PCID = PCM2.PCID
INNER JOIN pc_cat pcat 
  ON p.category_id = pcat.cat_id 
  and p.fea_ind = 'Y' AND p.act_ind = 'Y'
order by pcid
```