# SQL oracle Select condition in group

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's suppose I have a table with 3 columns:

```
ID | GroupId | DateCreatedOn |
```

I want to select the datas grouped by GroupId so:

```
select GroupId from tableName group by GroupId;
```

But what if I want to execute another select on each group? let's suppose now that I want the last created row (DateCreatedOn) of each group?

Also, I would like to retrieve ALL the columns and not only the GroupId.

Im kind of lost because I only have GroupId available.

Please provide some explanation and not only the correct query.

Comment: Add some sample table data, and it's expected result.

Comment: General GROUP BY tip, a selected column should either be argument to a set function (e.g. AVG), or be listed in the group by clause. (Seldom both.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` for this:

```
SELECT ID, GroupId, DateCreatedOn
FROM (
  SELECT ID, GroupId, DateCreatedOn,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GroupId 
                            ORDER BY DateCreatedOn DESC) AS rn
  FROM mytable) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

`rn` field is equal to 1 for the record having the most recent `DateCreatedOn` value within each `GroupId` partition.

Comment: I deleted my comment because I made a mistake on my query. Your query leads me to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477085/oracle-partition-by-and-row-number-keyword where I could find a great explanation of Partition by. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can get the values with the maximum of another column using `KEEP ( DENSE_RANK [FIRST|LAST] ORDER BY ... )` in the aggregation:

```
SELECT   GroupID,
         MAX( ID ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY DateCreatedOn ) AS id
         MAX( DateCreatedOn ) AS DateCreatedOn
FROM     table_name
GROUP BY GroupId
```

You can also do it using `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT ID,
       GroupID,
       DateCreatedOn
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY GroupID
                             ORDER BY DateCreatedOn DESC, ID DESC ) AS RN
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE  RN = 1
```

*(`ID DESC` is added to the `ORDER BY` to get the maximum `ID` for the latest `DateCreatedOn` to give the same result as the first query; if you don't have a deterministic order then you are likely to get whichever row the database produces first and the result can be non-deterministic)*